# Run a script from within notepad++

Tags: plugins, notepad++, script

I would like to include one awk sript (logtool) which will use an opened notepad++ file to perform some filtering on the file, I used to make it in ultraedit very simply, How can I make it run in Notepad ? the script file is named logtool.exe and I would like to integrate it with argument for example logtool.exe /[F] to perform processing with the current file

Comment: you may want to change the title of the question from "Include a script in notepad" to "Include a script in Notepad++". maybe also add the "notepad++" and "script" tags

Comment: add a button in source code and recompile notepad++ is my solution, but it's probably more work than you wanted

Answer (score 0):

This is easy with Notepad++ plugin NppExec.

In the NppExec console window, just type:

```
  logtool.exe $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)
```

(You may have to put the full path to logtool.exe).

If this is what you're after, and if you use it a lot, you could ["productionise" this by making it an internal macro within Notepad++](https://superuser.com/a/464072/153054) and associating it with a keyboard shortcut.  That would save some typing.